# Communities Template "KOA" speed issues

Tags: community

My company is just starting to implement Communities. We are using Koa as a public facing knowledge site. We will not being using community licenses for logging in. Everything will be public facing for now. Our current issue is the speed of the site, **10-20 second load up times**. That is simply un-usable... Has anyone found a remedy to this? I have tried a 3 day page caching rule and saw a bit of an improvement. But honestly, more than 2-5 second load time is still unacceptable.

I am hoping that with the ability in Winter '16 to build lightning components I can modify the queries in the components on the front page to be more efficient (safe harbor =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winter '16 Lightning Templates seems to have cleared up speed issues.

Comment: Allen - what about the Napili template? I'm seeing exactly the same thing and I've updated to the Winter 16 templates.